# Op amp circuit for logrithm calculation?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier

How does one design an op amp circuit which calculates the logarithm of the incoming voltage? I.E. if \$V_{in}\$ is the voltage at the input of the circuit and \$V_{out}\$ is the voltage at the output of the circuit, then the relationship between the two should be
$$
V_{out}=\log_{10}\left(\frac{V_{in}}{V_{ref}}\right),
$$
where \$V_{ref}\$ is some reference voltage such as 1 V.

Comment: Application note 31 says?

Comment: I hope you don't remove this question as a duplicate.  My question is specifically about an op amp circuit, which is indeed very similar to the question linked, but @SpehroPefhany gave an answer which more specifically addresses my question.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't follow.

Comment: Only because you haven't looked at it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I take it you are referring to [this document from National Semiconductor?](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/bobpease/assets/AN-31.pdf) See what I did there? Thats called a link.  Regardless of the snarkiness, this is a very useful document, and I appreciate you pointing me towards it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a BJT, \$V_{BE} \approx\$ \$V_T \cdot ln(\$ \$ I_c \over I_S\$), where \$V_T = \$\$k \cdot T\over q\$, and \$I_S \$ is a transistor characteristic (saturation current).

So, it's a matter of scaling to get what you're asking for.

Recall that \$log_{10}(x)\$ = \$  ln(x)\over ln(10) \$.

[image]

The devil is in the details, however, and both \$I_S\$ and \$ V_T\$ are temperature dependent, so compensation is required, perhaps with a temperature-dependent resistance.

See this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35692/why-does-the-base-emitter-voltage-of-a-bjt-decrease-with-temperature).